# How to use Codeigniter View in Semantic UI tab?

Tags: php, codeigniter, semantic-ui

I used Semantic UI tabs components in one of my Codeigniter project. Here's the setup.

**main_view.php**

```
<div class="ui pointing secondary menu">
    <a class="active item" data-tab="tab1">Tab 1</a>
    <a class="item" data-tab="tab2">Tab 2</a>
    <a class="item" data-tab="tab3">Tab 3</a>
</div>
<div class="ui container">
    <div class="ui bottom attached active tab" data-tab="tab1"></div>
    <div class="ui bottom attached tab" data-tab="tab2"></div>
    <div class="ui bottom attached tab" data-tab="tab3"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.ui.menu > .item').tab({
            context: 'parent',
            auto: true,
            history: true,
            parseScripts: false,
            ignoreFirstLoad: false,
            cache: false,
            path: baseURL
        });
    });
</script>
```

**tab1.php / tab2.php / tab3.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <?= $data; ?>
</div>
```

**Main_View.php(Controller)**

```
public function index_get(){
    $this->load->view('setting');
}
public function tab1_get(){
    $data = 'tab 1';    
    $this->load->view('tab1', $data);
}
public function tab2_get(){
    $data = 'tab 2';
    $this->load->view('tab2', $data);
}
public function tab3_get(){
    $data = 'tab 3';
    $this->load->view('tab3', $data);
}
```

**routes.php**

```
$route['main'] = 'main_view';
$route['main/tab1'] = 'main_view/tab1';
$route['main/tab2'] = 'main_view/tab2';
$route['main/tab3'] = 'main_view/tab3';
```

Everything works fine with URLs like this

```
http://localhost/main#/tab1
http://localhost/main#/tab2
http://localhost/main#/tab3
```

But it just show me the tab content(without the tab bar) when I try to remove the hash in the URL. I also tried using historyType: 'state' in the tab js config but still broken. How can I prevent or redirect users to access the child pages only?